# Mysql insert data on table a when insert in table b

Tags: mysql, sql, select, triggers, insert

I want to do this:
If not exist data on my table MisLibros then Insert Value IdEbook from table ebook, but when I try CALL 
mysql says  :#1054 - Unknown column 'Ebook.IdEbook' in 'where clause'

PD: I don't want to use UPDATE, I need to do INSERT

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SPExistencia ( 

)
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT IdEbook FROM  MisLibros  WHERE Ebook.IdEbook= MisLibros.IdEbook)  THEN
INSERT INTO MisLibros (IdEbook) VALUES (NEW.IdEbook);

   ELSE 

   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'Ya cuentas con el libro seleccionado';

   END IF;
   COMMIT;

    END;
```

Comment: You have to create a trigger instead of procedure to implement this.

Comment: What is Ebook in the statement Ebook.IdEbook?

Comment: Can you help me please @saharsh ????? how can I create trigger, and how can I implement to a procedure? PLEASE!!!!

Comment: ebook (table name)  IdEbook (column name) @Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [**CREATE TRIGGER**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) syntax with example.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `TR_Ebook`$$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `TR_Ebook` AFTER INSERT ON `Ebook` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MisLibros WHERE NEW.IdEbook = MisLibros.IdEbook) THEN 
            INSERT INTO MisLibros (IdEbook) 
            VALUES (NEW.IdEbook);
        END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ok... I create trigger, so how can I implement to a stored procedure?

Comment: or you have an e-mail where can I send documentation of my db ?